# writing and testing a custom loss or metric function for keras model

Tags: python, keras, metrics, loss-function

I try to use machine learning techniques to predict time to events. My predictions will be probability vectors v of length 20, v[i] being
the probability that the event occurs in i + 1 days (i ranges from 0 to 19).

How can I test the custom loss and metric functions I write?

I'd like to use the following loss and metric to train a model :

[image: equation using Online Equation Editor]

[image: equation using Online Equation Editor]

Her's how I tried to implement it :

```
from keras import backend as K

def weighted_meansquare(y_true, y_pred):
    w = K.constant(np.array([i + 1 for i in range(20)]))
    return K.sum(K.square(w * y_pred - w * y_true))

def esperance_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    w = K.constant(np.array([i + 1 for i in range(20)]))
    return K.sum(w * y_true - w * y_true)
```

I expected the model to minimize the metric (which is basically an expectation since my model returns a probability vector). Yet when I try to fit my model I see that the metric is always 0.0000e+00 .

What I'm looking for is :

1. some specific tips about how to code these functions
2. some general tips about testing keras.backend functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in your definition of `esperance_metric`: you use `y_true - y_true` instead of `y_pred - y_true`, which is why your metric is always 0.

I also see a mistake in `weighted_meansquare`. You should multiple by `w` after taking the square as follows:

```
K.sum(w * K.square(y_pred - y_true))
```

In general, if you want to test backend functions you can try evaluating them with `K.eval`. For example:

```
y_pred = K.constant([1.] * 20)
y_true = K.constant([0.] * 20)
print(K.eval(esperance_metric(y_true, y_pred)))
```

Comment: My bad those silly mistakes are precisely the reason why I needed to test my code. K.eval did the trick. Unit tests here I come... Thank you very much!